# file explorer in Eclipse java project

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse 3.8 and java project inside of it. I have project explorer window, but can't find file explorer. I need it to edit configuration files. How to see all files in project?

Comment: Project Explorer shows you most things. What configuration files do you want to change?

Comment: I would like to edit .properties file that in bin folder. Unfortunately bin folder is even not visible in project explorer

Answer (score 0):

Select Project Explorer's View menu (the one with the down-arrow icon). Then select 'Customize View'. In the Filter tab, ensure that '.resources' and 'Java output folders' entries are un-selected. This should then allow you to view that configuration file in this view.